# Number of OS can be install on the Harddisk

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, windows-7, windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows XP, in three different partitions and after I install Grub loadder, I am getting only two(ubuntu and Windows XP) entries in the grub menu, there is no option to boot in to windows 7. Can we make three entries in grub menu for each ubuntu, Windows 7 and windows XP ?

---

Sorry for the delay reply.....

Here is my result.txt content, I not found the link to attach the file that is why I copy and paste here:

```
                   Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v1.97-1.98) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks in partition 9 for (,msdos9)/boot/grub.

sda1: __________________________________________

 File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /boot.ini /grldr /bootmgr /Boot/BCD 
                   /Windows/System32/winload.exe /grldr /ntldr 
                   /NTDETECT.COM
sda2: __________________________________________

 File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows XP
Boot files:        
sda3: __________________________________________

 File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
sda5: __________________________________________

 File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                   at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                   sda5 starts at sector 144761778.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        
sda6: __________________________________________

 File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                   at sector 63.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        
sda7: __________________________________________

 File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
sda8: __________________________________________

 File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda8 starts 
                   at sector 2048.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        
sda9: __________________________________________

 File system:       ext3
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 10.10
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img
============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _______________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition Boot Start Sector End Sector # of Sectors Id System

/dev/sda1 * 63 102,815,999 102,815,937 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda2 102,816,000 144,761,714 41,945,715 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda3 144,761,776 312,580,095 167,818,320 f W95 Extended (LBA) /dev/sda5 144,761,778 186,707,429 41,945,652 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda6 186,707,493 228,653,144 41,945,652 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda7 228,655,104 232,652,799 3,997,696 82 Linux swap / Solaris /dev/sda8 232,654,848 274,597,887 41,943,040 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS /dev/sda9 274,599,936 312,580,095 37,980,160 83 Linux

"blkid" output: ____________________________________

Device UUID TYPE LABEL

/dev/sda1 4F80ED6F4F79B298 ntfs Windows 7 /dev/sda2 DACC8581CC8558A1 ntfs Windows XP /dev/sda5 4226-4FE4 vfat SOFTWARES /dev/sda6 6A089A1A0899E57B ntfs JYOSTHNA /dev/sda7 6632a4a7-470c-4def-85a7-077a3df6b0b5 swap
/dev/sda8 D89A1F099A1EE432 ntfs Entertainment /dev/sda9 e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 ext3

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device Mount_Point Type Options

/dev/sda1 /media/Windows 7 fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions) /dev/sda2 /media/Windows XP fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions) /dev/sda5 /media/SOFTWARES vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush) /dev/sda6 /media/JYOSTHNA fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions) /dev/sda8 /media/Entertainment fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions) /dev/sda9 / ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)

================================ sda1/boot.ini: ================================

[Boot Loader]

timeout=30

Default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS

[Operating Systems]

multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect

=========================== sda9/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

#

DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#

It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then set have_grubenv=true load_env fi set default="0" if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}" save_env saved_entry set prev_saved_entry= save_env prev_saved_entry set boot_once=true fi

function savedefault { if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then saved_entry="${chosen}" save_env saved_entry fi }

function recordfail { set recordfail=1 if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi }

function load_video { insmod vbe insmod vga }

insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then set gfxmode=640x480 load_video insmod gfxterm fi terminal_output gfxterm insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale set lang=en insmod gettext if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then set timeout=-1 else set timeout=10 fi

END /etc/grub.d/00_header
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
set menu_color_normal=white/black set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os { recordfail insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic root=UUID=e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 ro quiet splash initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic } menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os { recordfail insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 echo 'Loading Linux 2.6.35-22-generic ...' linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic root=UUID=e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 ro single echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...' initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic }

END /etc/grub.d/10_linux
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" { insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin } menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" { insmod part_msdos insmod ext2 set root='(hd0,msdos9)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set e90f6c3b-aba9-4ba0-9eb7-e499468664e4 linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8 }

END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
menuentry "Windows NT/2000/XP (on /dev/sda1)" { insmod part_msdos insmod ntfs set root='(hd0,msdos1)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 4f80ed6f4f79b298 drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} chainloader +1 }

END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom
This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries. Simply type the
menu entries you want to add after this comment. Be careful not to change
the 'exec tail' line above.
END /etc/grub.d/40_custom
BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom
if [ -f $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then source $prefix/custom.cfg; fi

### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

=============================== sda9/etc/fstab: ================================

/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#

Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#

proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0 /dev/sda9 / ext3 errors=remount-ro 0 1

swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=6632a4a7-470c-4def-85a7-077a3df6b0b5 none swap sw 0 0

/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0

=================== sda9: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

        GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
148.744281769 = 159.712956416 boot/grub/core.img 1 148.774848938 = 159.745777664 boot/grub/grub.cfg 1 148.785129547 = 159.756816384 boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic 6 148.704105377 = 159.669817344 boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic 3 148.785129547 = 159.756816384 initrd.img 6 148.704105377 = 159.669817344 vmlinuz 3

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda3

00000000 fb 92 00 79 84 42 e2 51 d7 51 e9 12 f0 5b 49 db |...y.B.Q.Q...[I.| 00000010 0d 3c c3 5e 0b d5 2f 5c 74 f4 00 01 6a 96 6a ca |.<.^../\t...j.j.| 00000020 9e c0 00 be d3 fc 42 fc 7e 6d 75 8a bf f5 c0 eb |......B.~mu.....| 00000030 d1 28 7b d4 cc cf 54 bd c5 54 57 5f e2 f0 41 26 |.({...T..TW_..A&| 00000040 83 36 b1 99 29 44 00 03 40 29 0e 20 7e 81 9c 7a |.6..)D..@). ~..z| 00000050 89 4a 95 c9 a1 9e 67 d8 d2 c2 9a 39 96 1c 80 a1 |.J....g....9....| 00000060 2c ae 62 21 ad 13 86 b3 e3 22 dd 14 ea a7 19 eb |,.b!....."......| 00000070 5e 60 8a f9 48 36 90 30 83 4d ea d2 57 c7 4f e9 |^..H6.0.M..W.O.| 00000080 f9 9f dc fc 9d a5 ad 14 b2 fb cf 5e 2f 99 8b 4e |...........^/..N| 00000090 f6 09 46 4a ba 13 e7 54 c0 e8 06 a0 d3 9f f3 f4 |..FJ...T........| 000000a0 a1 00 00 08 0c 08 4e 61 0b 99 20 88 53 24 a5 5e |......Na.. .S$.^| 000000b0 1a aa c1 e9 63 11 f7 e5 f8 95 c0 76 5d 01 79 d8 |....c......v].y.| 000000c0 f8 ea e1 e4 80 b0 e0 2b 5a 5a 07 89 c5 9a 7d f7 |.......+ZZ....}.| 000000d0 14 98 c3 88 d4 3d f9 6e ab 17 bb a6 78 0b 1b 48 |.....=.n....x..H| 000000e0 34 9e fa 75 d5 9d bd 55 74 e1 a0 33 68 aa ba 94 |4..u...Ut..3h...| 000000f0 b6 de 67 58 ab e9 d5 cd 97 67 04 cf 9c e6 56 7e |..gX.....g....V~| 00000100 6f 9d 7b 39 f3 b2 db f1 d5 9f ee 7e 18 26 7b 67 |o.{9.......~.&{g| 00000110 67 be ff d7 9b fc cc de 65 e0 b4 b2 03 60 fa 45 |g.......e.....E| 00000120 9b ca 07 5d f5 96 48 00 00 00 40 22 29 20 e7 20 |...]..H...@") . | 00000130 00 09 44 29 06 ad 69 4a 29 5c 79 6d 24 6e c3 91 |..D)..iJ)\ym$n..| 00000140 6d 9d d7 62 07 9a 65 18 b2 f8 bb 99 c8 43 00 e3 |m..b..e......C..| 00000150 86 ab 15 e3 99 18 f2 78 5a 81 11 b6 0d 9f b0 c6 |.......xZ.......| 00000160 8c dd 6d 7e af bb a6 3a 85 a9 a6 09 f9 ff c5 6e |..m~...:.......n| 00000170 e7 2c 29 a3 3c ac 88 e8 c5 9b ed 40 b7 ff e5 82 |.,).<......@....| 00000180 68 f2 c7 d5 9c f5 76 6b bd 93 19 fb ff f6 78 d1 |h.....vk......x.| 00000190 37 ff 87 1e 7d 2f ef 5a dc b0 36 8b a1 f0 18 3e |7...}/.Z..6....>| 000001a0 f8 ff fb 90 00 80 00 04 2d 4a d8 1e 61 80 00 88 |........-J..a...| 000001b0 87 fa f3 cc 3c 00 0a f9 0d 6a fc 94 00 01 00 01 |....<....j......| 000001c0 c1 ff 07 fe ff ff 02 00 00 00 34 0a 80 02 00 fe |..........4.....| 000001d0 ff ff 05 fe ff ff 36 0a 80 02 73 0a 80 02 00 00 |......6...s.....| 000001e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................| 000001f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa |..............U.| 00000200
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we make three entries in grub menu for each ubuntu, Windows 7 and windows XP ?

Yes, grub and burg do no prevent you. The gpt partitioning scheme can have 128 partitions inside and there are manual methods to get 145.

- Do not forget: **Windows** only boots from a primary partition.
- See http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ To check your installation please follow the steps in the link and add the Results.txt to your question. This will show us how you installed your operating systems.

---

Edit:

What you have there is not going to work but it is MicroSoft that is the problem: they do not let you install 2 operating systems on the same disc. Linux does not have this as a restriction. Your results.txt shows this:

- sda1 = disc 1, partition 1. W7.
- sda2 = disc 1, partition 2. XP.
- sda3 = disc 1, partition 3. Linux.

Windows can only be installed on a 'partition 1'.

So to use 2 windows in dual boot setting you need 2 hard discs (the 2nd being sda2 where you can use partition 1 for 1 of the 2 windows).

- You need to install Windows 7 after Windows XP. Windows XP does not support booting Windows 7.

---

Possible workaround: install Windows XP in virtualBox from within Ubuntu. So you get 2 operating systems and after you started Ubuntu you can start XP (and use both at the same time).

Comment: Thank you, I understand your reply, I try with your suggestion, only one thing what I worry is my hard disk is so many times formated nearly more than 15 to 20 times from the time I got the system and just a month back I formated I afraid to format again, please suggest me on this